# 'Quick select' date ranges - from web forms to Stock Markets is there a unifying standard? (and should there be?)

Tags: info-visualisation, data

I see two major schools of thought/implementations of 'quick select' date range options:

**A) General web apps**

| today | yesterday | last 7 days | last month | last 3 months | ...etc. | Custom |

Usually presented in some form of selectbox/dropdown list - i.e. hidden requiring discovery as to which ones are available.
As seen in [google adwords](http://google.com/adwords), google adsense et al.

**B) Stock markets and mobile**

| 1d | 4w | 3m | 6m | 1y | custom |

Usually presented as is, simple text, click to view (does not require discovery).
As seen in [Yahoo Stocks](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=GOOG+Interactive#symbol=goog;range=1d;), and iphone stock apps example (cannot provide more than 2 links as a new user)

I am interested to do a little poll on the above.. please answer either A or B for your preference, along with any appropriate discussion on topic relating to UX of both/either method.

Comment: Note that those things are, as you say, 'quick selects'. They are nothing more than shortcuts and never a replacement for scrolling and zooming in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your use scenario for the date range selection. But I want to try to give an answer.
The solution (B) corrensponds with typical durations (terms) of financial instruments on the stock markets e.g. a bonds has a duration of 5Y. In my opinion, this date range solution is intuitive for this kind of case. Solution (A) will be used for general date ranges. 
A nice solution is the date range selectors with drag&drop. You should test both version with your customers and your use cases.

Other platforms (e.g. Bloomberg and EUREX) used the same data range selection.

[image: EUREX]

---

[image: BLOOMBERG]

Comment: Good answer, imo. One can never define a 'unifying stndard' as it really depends on the context in which you are using it.

Comment: @sysscore:@BaGi Thanks for feedback. That was the "(and should there be?)" component of my question.